# Set two buttons in the same column with space using angular JS Boostrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, button, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my website I am trying to create two buttons in same column. I want set some space between these two buttons. I am very new in this programing language. I tried all the way I have seen from web. I could not succedd to do that. Here is the piece of my code where I am trying to create two buttons

```
       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12" >
            <button
                 class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                 translate="TECHNICAL_DETAILS"
                 ng-click="$ctrl.techDetails(conflict)"
            ></button>

           <button
              class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
              ng-if="$ctrl.isConflictEditable(conflict)"
              translate="RESOLVE_CONFLICT"
              ng-disabled="!conflict.active"
              ng-click="$ctrl.editConflict(conflict)"
           ></button>
           <button
             class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
             ng-if="!$ctrl.isConflictEditable(conflict)"
             translate="RESOLVE_CONFLICT_NOW"
             ng-disabled="!conflict.active"
             ng-click="$ctrl.resolveConflict(conflict)"
          ></button>

          </div>
      </div>
```

You're using BOOTSTRAP classes and buttons are showing in a single row. You can insert the buttons in different sections and use the available classes to align two sections.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="firstBtnSection">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" translate="TECHNICAL_DETAILS" ng-click="$ctrl.techDetails(conflict)"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="secondBtnSection">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-if="$ctrl.isConflictEditable(conflict)" translate="RESOLVE_CONFLICT" ng-disabled="!conflict.active" ng-click="$ctrl.editConflict(conflict)"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-if="!$ctrl.isConflictEditable(conflict)" translate="RESOLVE_CONFLICT_NOW" ng-disabled="!conflict.active" ng-click="$ctrl.resolveConflict(conflict)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can add some margin for "secondBtnSection" div element.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are using bootsrtap. So, you could add a class `mr-3` to first and second button, and it would add some margin between buttons

Comment: How can I add this class, I already adedd btn-primary pull-right inside btn

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right mr-3" ng-if="$ctrl.isConflictEditable(conflict)" translate="RESOLVE_CONFLICT" ng-disabled="!conflict.active" ng-click="$ctrl.editConflict(conflict)"></button>